# Conflicted internal SD card because of casing/capitalization?

Tags: internal-storage, file-system

I'm using two Tencent apps. One of them likes accessing `/sdcard/tencent` and the other likes `/sdcard/Tencent`. Somehow the `/data/media/0/Tencent` folder is empty and `/sdcard/Tencent` has exactly the same contents as `/sdcard/tencent`, so they worked fine for a while.

Recently I did something unrelated but eats a lot of RAM, and most of the background apps were shut down including the two mentioned above. To my surprise, `/sdcard/Tencent` was no longer mapped to `/sdcard/tencent` but they have reversed! I checked `/data/media/0/tencent` and everything that was there is still there, but `/data/media/0/Tencent` is no longer empty.

A reboot **has a chance(!!)** to fix the issue. Now I would like to know the cause of this strange behavior, and a possible solution.

---

I quickly merged `Tencent` into `tencent` in `/data/media/0` and created an empty *file*, and to my surprise `/sdcard/Tencent` is still showing up as a directory, not the file.

Answer (score 0):

I have a dirty fix but I still want a better solution.

Just delete the unwanted variant and re-create it, then both names would be mapped to the other (desired) one. However, this needs to be done once per reboot.